# How to use HighChart.getOption() with react-native-highchart

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, highcharts

I am using highchart on react-native with [this](https://github.com/TradingPal/react-native-highcharts) library. I have created simple activity gauge component from high chart official site. Here is the code of component.

```
import ChartView from 'react-native-highcharts';
import React, { Component } from 'react';

export default class Speedometer extends Component {



    render() {
      var Highcharts='Highcharts';
      var conf={


     chart: {
            type: 'solidgauge',
            height: '110%',

        },
        ....
        series: [{
            name: 'Move',
            data: [{
                color: Highcharts.getOptions().colors[0],
                radius: '112%',
                innerRadius: '88%',
                y: 80
            }]
        }, {
            name: 'Exercise',
            data: [{
                color: Highcharts.getOptions().colors[1],
                radius: '87%',
                innerRadius: '63%',
                y: 65
            }]
        }, {
            name: 'Stand',
            data: [{
                color: Highcharts.getOptions().colors[2],
                radius: '62%',
                innerRadius: '38%',
                y: 50
            }]
        }]
    };

      const options = {
          global: {
              useUTC: false
          },
          lang: {
              decimalPoint: ',',
              thousandsSep: '.'
          }
      };

      return (
        <ChartView style={{height:300}} more guage config={conf} options={options}></ChartView>
      );
    }
}
```

When i render this component on my screen i get the error

```
TypeError: TypeError: TypeError: TypeError: undefined is not a function (evaluating 'Highcharts.getOptions()')
```

How can i use getOptions or colors or theme or other variable with highchart inside react-native component.

Comment: you still need to `import Highcharts from 'highcharts'` - the other is a wrapper.

Comment: after the import i am getting this error `TypeError: undefined is not a function (evaluating '_highcharts.default.getOptions()')`

Comment: `REMEMBER to declare the variable Highcharts='Highcharts'` - this has overwritten it. dunno what it's supposed to do when it assigns it to a string...

Comment: you mean i need to add the `import Highcharts from 'highcharts'` and `Highcharts='Highcharts'` both ?

Comment: no, not tried the react native one but in react web port, you need to only do the import, not the `var Highcharts = 'Highcharts'`.

Comment: it is recommended by the library that i need to declare highcharts in this way.. any way still not working

Comment: Hi Ahsan Sohail, I think that your problem is closely related to `react-native-highcharts` library, so you should ask this question directly on their github.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to understand a few things here:

1. `react-native-highcharts` library create a dynamic html content and then inject into webview. Whatever is passed in the `config` props of `ChartView` is converted in to string content after `flattenObject` function inside the library.
2. If you look at the starting code of html content inside the library you would see that some javascript dependencies has been included and one of them is `highcharts`. This highcharts library will make the variable `Highcharts` in the local scope of javascript inside webview.
3. You are getting this error because React thinks that `Highchart` must be define somewhere in the component and define `Highchart` as a string, so if you access string.function it will throw error.
4. (Solution) you have two option here either to tweak the code inside the library and make it to accept flat string as props and pass this string directly to the `ChartView`, or you can create dummy `Highchart` object inside your root component to make the `React` stop complaining about the `Highchart` object. Once this object is passed through `CharView` highchart would be available in javascript scope inside webview and BOOM you Charts are loading.

Now you know the problem you can come up with more solutions. Hope this helps!